# Work computer python package installation fail

Tags: python, pip, package, conda

i try to install a package sklearn-crfsuite https://pypi.org/project/sklearn-crfsuite/#files on my working computer in windows, where I do not have admin rights. Besides the root enviorment I already created my own enviorment following called: Test.

Normally I use anacando navigator to install new packages, there everything works fine, but this package is not in anaconda navigator, so I am opening the anaconda prompt /conda prompt to install in manually. Here the problem starts.

I start by choosing the right enviorment in the command line:
`activate Test`

I installed pip and scikit already and have the python version 3.6.8. So I try to run the following command:
`pip install sklearn-crfsuite`

And I get the error: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sklearn-crfsuite 
Error: no matching distrubation found for sklearn-crfsuite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a soluation on my own, for everyone who will have this problem at some time, search for the package on anaconda cloud:
https://anaconda.org/derickl/sklearn-crfsuite

the command is changing just a little bit then:
`conda install -c derickl sklearn-crfsuite`

where derickl denotes the cloud.